# How to check if SQL Server crashed

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm building a fully automated process for my company, which includes 2 processes. One, where a 3rd party application that off a stored procedure, at certain times per day. Two, the stored procedure then controls kicking off other processes. The procedure is controlled by a table with the list of jobs that will be kicked off for the day. If the status for the job item is set to Queue, the procedure will start running that item and set the status to Running. My problem is, if for some reason SQL Server crashes, whether it be a power outage or some odd reason. If the 3rd party application goes and kicks of that stored procedure another day, there might be a job that still says running which should've failed or set back to Queue since the server crashed.

Is there a way in SQL where I can check if the server crashed during the time a process is being ran?

Comment: If you wrap it status to Running in a transaction then if SQL crashes I think the status is not committed.   You could test with intentionally cracking SQL (just stop down the service).

Answer (score 0):

you may put your script and 3rd party application in one SQL job on the SQL server.  that may resolve the issue.

Comment: Hi oiek kent, thanks for replying. I don't think the 3rd party application can be called from SQL Server. The 3rd party application is $Universe. All we are using it to do is schedule task, sort of like a Windows scheduler but overkill.

Comment: actual you can.  in the "new job" -> steps -> "New..." there is a type call shell command, you can use windows command / exe file or wrap it in a batch file